# Print the actual Ruby code of a block?

Tags: ruby

Is this possible?

```
def block_to_s(&blk)
  #code to print blocks code here
end

puts block_to_s do
  str = "Hello"
  str.reverse!
  print str
end
```

This would print the follow to the terminal:

```
str = "Hello"
str.reverse!
print str
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question is related to:

- [Converting Proc and Method to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733162/)
- [How to extract the code from a Proc object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811501/)
- [Ruby block to string instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082741/)
- [Compare the Content, Not the Results, of Procs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404362/)

1. before Ruby 2.0, you can use the `.to_source` method
2. Ruby 2.0 and higher
   `.to_source` has been replaced by `.source`
3. using the gem 'sourcify', you can get something close to the block, but not exactly the same:

   require 'sourcify'

   def block_to_s(&blk)
   blk.to_source(:strip_enclosure => true)
   end

   puts block_to_s {
   str = "Hello"
   str.reverse!
   print str
   }

In above, notice that you either have to put parentheses around the argument of `puts` (`block_to_s` ... `end`) or use `{...}` instead of `do ... end` because of the strength of connectivity as discussed repeatedly in stackoverflow.

This will give you:

```
str = "Hello"
str.reverse!
print(str)
```

which is equivalent to the original block as a ruby script, but not the exact same string.

4. also see the method_source gem
   github.com/banister/method_source

Comment: In Ruby 2.0 you can print a proc as a string with #source.

#to_source no longer works.

Comment: You need to include the `method_source` gem (and you will need to be in a file, it did not work from irb for me)

Comment: A quick link to the method_source gem: https://github.com/banister/method_source